# Easier way to format dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Never understood why SQL Server doesn't let you specify a custom date format like:

```
CONVERT(varchar(22),yourdate,'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM')
```

and that you have to use the style numbers they provide, and then use REPLACE, SUBSTRING etc. to come up with the format you want.

Is there a better way? What is the best way to come up with the (pretty common) format I want above? Anything I come up with is way too complex.

Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server **2012** now does have a `FORMAT` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: Because formatting should be left to the front end. Once you format it the value is a string and sorting operations in the front end will get pretty wonky.

Comment: @SeanLange: in general I agree with you, but there *are* situations where you have to do the formatting in SQL and the missing `format` function in earlier versions *really* hurt there (it goes both ways btw: sometimes you need to process dates that come as strings e.g. from other systems or flat files. Parsing them isn't really that flexible either)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The available `FORMAT()` function also hurts in 2012+ ... have you ever tested the performance? I have, and it's abysmal. I don't know of many scenarios where the formatting absolutely has to be done in the database... who's consuming it *in the database* that needs to see it in a regional, ambiguous string format? In all other cases, I will opt for `CONVERT(,style)` or leave use `Format()` in C# etc.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you can use a specific format in your "dates" according to your needs, so, SQL Server provide you a lot of functions for this kind of situations.

**SQL SERVER 2008**

```
SELECT  
CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST( SUBSTRING(CAST(20070807000000 AS VARCHAR),1,8) 
AS DATETIME ), 103)
```

Result: 07/08/2007

You can see more formats [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.100).aspx)

**SQL SERVER 2012 & 2014**

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '10/01/2011';
SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'en-US' ) AS 'US English Result'
,FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'en-gb' ) AS 'Great Britain English Result'
```

US English Result: 10/1/2011

Great Britain English Result: 01/10/2011

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505(v=sql.120).aspx)

---

**SET DATEFORMAT**

Remember that you can use this clause if you want to change the format of your dates in your query.

Example:

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD -- You can use 'DMY' or 'MDY'
SELECT GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate the format you specified, I would use part of style 101 and part of style 109 (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.100).aspx), like so:

```
CONVERT(CHAR(11), @YourDatetime, 101) + STUFF(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(26), @YourDatetime, 109), 14), 9, 4, ' ')
```